# Mock FirebaseRemoteConfig getBoolean()

Tags: android, firebase, junit, mockito, firebase-remote-config

I have a unit test that requires me to return either a `true` or `false` for a firebase config entry. But even if I set the mock to `true` it always returns `false` when the unit test is run.

#### Here is my mock:

```
doReturn(true).when(mock(FirebaseRemoteConfig.class)).getBoolean(any());
```

#### And here is the code with the `true` or `false` condition

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
boolean useHttp = firebaseRemoteConfig.getBoolean(RemoteConfigKeys.PUSH_RECEIVED_USE_HTTP);
```

`useHttp` is always `false`

#### Test dependencies:

```
    // Unit test dependencies
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    testImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.2.0"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-playservices:4.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-5"
    kaptTest 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.4"
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Would love to see how you did it if so :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement is equivalent to this:

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig aTemporaryExistingJavaObject = mock(FirebaseRemoteConfig.class);
doReturn(true).when(aTemporaryExistingJavaObject).getBoolean(any());
```

It does not work, because your productive code is not using that mock (it will not be returned by `FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()`).

You need a way to inject the mock into the tested class, e.g.

- pass it into the tested method
- pass it into the constructor
- call `FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()` in a protected method, that is spied in the test